# How to fetch all rows at once with Oracle JDBC driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I have a query that returns ~6,000 rows. I need all rows to be returned so they can be used to generate an R script which performs a batch job. My method to execute the query and iterate over the ResultSet populating an ArrayList was taking 3 seconds (which the customer complained was too slow). I got this down to 0.7 seconds by running an initial query to get the row count then setting the Fetch Size of the PreparedStatement to this count.

Old (condensed) code:

```
public List<MyClass> loadFromDb() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT a, b FROM table1, table2, LEFT JOIN table3...";
        ResultSet result = connection.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
        List<MyClass> values = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            values.add(new MyClass(result.getString(1), result.getString(2)));
        }
        result.close();
        return values;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

New code: (notice that we can now initalize the ArrayList to the exact size required)

```
public List<MyClass> loadFromDb() {
    try {
        String sqlWithoutSelectClause = " FROM table1, table2, LEFT JOIN table3...";
        int rowCount = getCount(sqlWithoutSelectClause);
        String sql = "SELECT a, b" + sqlWithoutSelectClause;
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setFetchSize(rowCount);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        List<MyClass> values = new ArrayList<>(rowCount);
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            values.add(new MyClass(result.getString(1), result.getString(2)));
        }
        result.close();
        return values;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

private int getCount(String sqlWithoutSelectClause) {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) " + sqlWithoutSelectClause;
    try {
        ResultSet result = connection.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
        result.next();
        int count = result.getInt(1);
        result.close();
        return count;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am just using JDBC, not Hibernate. I am connecting to an Oracle database.

My question is whether there is a more efficient method for fetching all the rows at once than executing an extra query to get the row count. I can't find a way to set the Fetch Size to "all rows".

Comment: There is no need to set the fetch size equal to the total rowcount. Typically any fetch size beyond 1000 does not change the performance very much (except for very, very slow network connections). The default fetch size is 10, increasing that to 100 usually is enough. Just try it with different fetch sizes. I would be very surprised if you see any improvement beyond 1000.

Comment: Could you measure the time from the call to `executeQuery` until the first record appears (that is, the query execution time) - is it 0.5 seconds or maybe 2.5 seconds from these 3 seconds? This will tell you how long the query itself is performed (prepared, executed etc), and how long the data itself is sent.

Comment: and what do you do if your db query return 1,000,000 records? Fetching them all will then probably crash your app

Comment: Make sure you close all resources with try-with-resources, including the `PreparedStatement` and the `ResultSet`